# How to use foreach to return true/false

Tags: php

How can I use foreach to return true or false.

For example, this isn't working.

```
function checkArray($myArray) {
    foreach( $myArray as $key=>$value ) {
       if(!$value == $condition) {
          return false;
       }
       else {
          return true;
       }
}

if ($checkArray == true) {
// do something
}
```

What is the correct syntax for using foreach as true/false function? If you can't do it, could you use it to change an existing variable to true/false instead?

Comment: `if (checkArray($array) == true) {` or `if (checkArray($array)) {`

Comment: Also `$condition` is not defined...

Comment: doing a return INSIDE the loop like you are will simply terminate the loop on the first iteration...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You would return `true` if the element was found/condition is true. And **after** the loop return `false` - if it had been found, this statement wouldn't have been reached.

```
function checkArray($myArray) {
    foreach($myArray as $key => $value) {
        if ($value == $condition) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

if (checkArray($array) === true) {
    // ...
}
```

Of course `true` and `false` are interchangeable, depending on what output you expect.

Answer (score 3):

If you're just trying to find a value you can use

```
if (in_array($lookup, $arrayToSearch)) { }
```

It'll be more efficient than enumerating the whole array.